# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: none). No matching distribution found

Tags: tensorflow, pip, pycharm, python-3.7, python-venv

I created a virtual environment in Pycharm for Python 3.7
But when I try to install a lower version of Tensorflow in that venv, using

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```

I get this error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15
```

My pip is upgraded. 
MY OS is Arch  Linux.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install python 64-bit version? Last week one my students had the exact same problem on Windows and it was because he installed 32-bit version instead of 64-bit version.

Comment: its a 64bit version

Comment: What do commands `pip -V` and `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"` return?

Comment: I installed miniconda and then installed the tensorflow on it. For some reason that added (base) to my terminal prompt so ```pip -V```  returns ```pip 20.0.2``` and ```python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])" ``` returns ```cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64```. But this is from miniconda and not my local machine environment. Haven't figured out how exit from miniconda yet.

Comment: Probably conda prepends stuff to your `PATH` env var, I'd start with checking in `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`/`/etc/profile.d/*` files.